# Sub-group of the modulo group is an ideal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, ideals

how do I show that every sub-group of ring $Z_n$ is an ideal in $Z_n$?

If $n$ is prime, the only sub-groups are the trivial and that mean's they are ideals, but if $n$ isn't prime, there are non trivial groups.

My second thought is that every sub-group is $mZ_n$ for $0<m<n$ and then it isn't hard to show that it is an ideal, but is it correct and how do I prove it generally (that there isn't any ideal from another form) ?

Comment: You just need to know that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian. In an abelian group, every subgroup is normal

Comment: I don't see how it help's me to conclude that any sub-group is ideal, what mean's that for any $i\in I$ for a sub-group $I$ and for any $a\in Z_n$, $${a*i}\in I$$

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking for normal subgroups. I would replace the word 'group' in your question with the word 'ring' to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the observations below:

- Every subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z $ corresponds to a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ that contains $n \mathbb Z$.
- The subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ that contain $n \mathbb Z$ are precisely $d\mathbb Z$, with $d$ a divisor of $n$.
- Every subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is an ideal.
- The canonical group homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is actually a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal has to be a subgroup (of the additive group of the ring) to begin with. So if you prove that all subgroups are already ideals, you are done.

**PS** Just correct the statement

> every sub-group is $mZ_n$ for $0<m<n$

to

> every subgroup is of the form $m Z_{n}$ for $m \mid n$.

Comment: And why the last sentence is correct ? Because as I mentioned, if n isn't prime, so we can write it as $n=pq$ and then $p|n$ and $q|n$, but why then the only sub-groups are from the form $pZ_{n}$ and $qZ_{n} $?

Comment: A cyclic group of order $n$ has precisely one subgroup of each order dividing $n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Subgroups_and_notation).

Comment: Right, and $Z_{n}$ ic cyclic for any $n$, $Z_{n}=<1>$, right ?

Comment: Hm ... I understood what you write, but i'm stil dont see the reason, why if there is one group of each order that devides n, that implies that each such sub-group is a multiply of the group by the order's devider. 
There is something missing in that explanation.